# Angular 4/5 - Change base href dynamically

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular5

I am working on a multi-tenant application with Ex URL: "https://example.com/{**portalID**}/Login" where `portalID` changes customer to customer. So the initial login looks like this.
 https://example.com/portalId/Login
 In the login page, I have a text box and a button. So the text box accepts `portalId` and onclick, I want to change the `portalId` in the URL without page reload.

Code:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { APP_BASE_HREF, Location } from '@angular/common';

import { AppComponent } from './';
import { getBaseLocation } from './shared/common-functions.util';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  providers: [
    appRoutingProviders,
    {
        provide: APP_BASE_HREF,
        useFactory: getBaseLocation
    },
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }

export function getBaseLocation() {
    let basePath = sessionStorage.getItem('portalId') || 'portalId'; // Default
    return '/' + basePath;
}
```

In production build, I was setting portalID as part of base href. 
Now Using test box I want to override the value.

For Client1:
So the initial URL is https://example.com/portalId/Login".
When I enter any number in the text box the URL should change to 
Ex: https://example.com/21/Login
Portal and JWT token I am storing in session storage.
After Successful login, every routing must have the portalID.
Something like this
https://example.com/21/home

For Client2: In New window (Now PortalId is 45)
The URL is  https://example.com/45/Login
Here also portalID and JWT token is saved in session storage.
After Successful login, every routing must have the portalID.
Something like this
https://example.com/45/home

Comment: you can achieve using routing isn't it?

Comment: @PardeepJain The application is multi-tenant how can I set base href value dynamically for multiple customers without page reload.
Note: I am able to set the value dynamically but I am actually reloading the page.

Comment: @user1985943 did my answer, answered your question?

Comment: @PatricioVargas
Thanks for the information but your answer is passing dynamic value in the routing.
But what i am trying to achieve is changing base href value based on client
Please let me know if my question is confusing .So that I will revisit my question.

Comment: @user1985943 so you are trying to do this for example: `<a href=" https://example.com/45/Login"></a>` and change it to `<a href=" https://example.com/76/Login"></a>` and that it actually takes you to the page of the 76 instead of the 45?

Answer (score 1):

This will have to be acomplished using routing. Follow this tutorial: https://www.learnhowtoprogram.com/javascript/angular-extended/dynamic-routing-navigation . You will have to set in your code the route you want to navigate to. Example:
 `this.router.navigate([**DyanamicPortalID**, 'Login']);`